# How to update Shapefile's Properties on PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, shapefile

**Context:** I'm building a WebApp with OpenLayers where users interact with some vector data (MultiLineStrings from Shapefiles) loaded from a GeoServer using WFS.

Basically they rate (like/dislike) some Features and choose the reasons why they like or dislike from a list. This information is easily stored in the Features using OpenLayers.

```
feature.set('Rating', 'Like');
```

For every user session I store all rated features as a GeoJSON into a PostGIS table. It works.

**Problem**: I'd like to also update a copy of the original Shapefile as a PostGIS table where each feature would contain a summary of all ratings. Let's say 87 users liked the feature with `id = 42`. I'd like my `feat.42` to have a LIKES property with value 87. And I'd like to directly update those LIKES in the DATABASE. Something like:

```
UPDATE schema.shapefile_table SET Likes = newValue WHERE id = 42
```

But, when I use `shp2pgsql` & `psql` to insert my shapefile to PostGIS I get something like:

[image: PostGIS table for my Shapefile]

I suspect the original features' properties aren't in my table but just their geographical information. So,

1. Am I right?
2. Is there any way to import a Shapefile to PostGIS including its properties? *(using `shp2pgsql | psql` or something as well non-interactive)*

In any case, is there a better scenario to solve what I'm trying to do?

**Edit:** My SQL file generated by:

```
shp2pgsql -G -I myshapefile.shp
```

looks like:

```
SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO UTF8;
SET STANDARD_CONFORMING_STRINGS TO ON;
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "myshapefile" (gid serial,
"id" int4,
"length" float8,
"geog" geography(MULTILINESTRING,4326));
ALTER TABLE "myshapefile" ADD PRIMARY KEY (gid);
INSERT INTO "myshapefile" ("id","length",geog) VALUES ('0','184.68','0105000020E61000000100000001020000000C000000944DB982ED76184155BE671D0C8F514152499DE0CC76184172DEFFF60B8F5141DA5889C9B8761841EE0912E40B8F5141BDFDB9A8987618419641B5C60B8F51417638BA4A75761841AA622AA90B8F51414FB0FF6A4D761841245F098E0B8F5141A48B4D3B05761841C47B0E620B8F51412A8E03AFB175184149BDA7330B8F514182C64C525175184154AA44FD0A8F5141E083D77EED74184155DD23CB0A8F5141041C4215547418410DE02D840A8F5141A702EE690B741841F644D74C0A8F5141');
INSERT INTO "myshapefile" ("id","length",geog) VALUES ('1','83.37','0105000020E610000001000000010200000006000000D2FD9CB278721841BA8443AC3A8F51415C1E6B669D72184177853ED53A8F51417C28D142F57218410CCB9F023B8F5141D670914B4173184146ED7E233B8F5141651BB86381731841268FA7433B8F5141931804E6C573184174081C773B8F5141');
...
CREATE INDEX ON "myshapefile" USING GIST ("geog");
COMMIT;
ANALYZE "myshapefile";
```

Comment: The attributes should be in your PostGis table. How did your shape2pgsql import looks like?

Comment: Thanks @Matte, I've edited my question adding information about the sql file generated by `shp2pgsql`.

Comment: you could try to use QGIS and its  DB Manager to import your shapefiles into your database. so you would be sure that all fields are in the shapefile are created in the table

Comment: Thanks @LaughU! I might try it while learning to see how the property fields are stored in the DB, but at last I'll need to do it programatically since those shapefiles will be uploaded to the server through a web form.

Comment: Your shp2pgsql command is strange. You use -G which does only deliver the attributes and should not deliver the geometries. What columns do you have in that shapefile? If you do not have a gis around just open the .dbf and have a look what columns are there. It seems the shapefile only has the columns "id" and "length". Should there be more?

Comment: Damn it! You're absolutely right @Matte. I was using a smaller file for testing that misses most of my real data properties except for `id` and `length`. I feel stupid now, but thank you so much for your time and help, guys! Should I delete this question?